# Is there any way to catch and store Error object from Error Boundary Event in Camunda Bpmn?

Tags: camunda, bpmn, zeebe

I have a REST Connector which when invoked can throw the Errors (Non 2xx Response). I've attached a Error Boundary Event to it which catches the Error by adding the following Error Handling in Rest Connector.

```
if error != null then
  bpmnError("STATE_UPDATE_ERROR", "STATE_UPDATE_ERROR")
else
  null
```

I'm looking for a way to get the Error object itself and store it in a variable.

Incase of happy flow, when the Rest Connector responds with 2xx response, I'm able to store the response using Response Mapping Thing as shown below.

[image]